# How should you implement an InterceptResponse method to handle Unauthorized Requests?

Tags: c#, .net, httprequest, openapi-generator

I am using OpenAPI Generator in a project, and it auto-generates an ApiClient class. The class has two partial methods:

```
partial void InterceptRequest(IRestRequest request);
partial void InterceptResponse(IRestRequest request, IRestResponse response);
```

I want to intercept responses with a 401 header, get a new token, and retry the request. I have created another partial class to implement these methods, but I don't know how they can return void. The generated file that calls these methods looks like this

```
InterceptRequest(req);
var response = client.Execute<T>(req);
InterceptResponse(req, response);
```

but C# is pass-by-value, so I cannot modify the response variable. I can also not modify the method signature, or reference to the methods because those files are auto-generated.

What is the abstract principal that I am suppose to follow? Am I supposed to let the 401 request go through, and fire off a new request to be intercepted? But if my app sees a 401, shouldn't I redirect to the login page? Or should I modify the methods to return the response type and just never generate the files again?

Answer (score 0):

What we do is modify the generated code to add in a `ref` before `response`:

```
InterceptResponse(req, **ref** response);
```

Our intercept code looks like this:

```
partial void InterceptResponse(IRestRequest req, **ref** IRestResponse response)
    {
        // Do something, wait, etc
        response = RestClient.Execute(request);
        // Do something else, check response, loop on 400, etc
    }
```

Because of the `ref`, the `response` object is changed in calling code.

Personally, I don't know why the `ref` isn't the default because without it you can't modify `response`, or pass back a new one, which is our flow. We also use it to rate limit our calls and to avoid quota blocks.